# Could not locate PHPMailer library

Tags: 6, emails

I am running a Drupal 6 site using the SMTP (6.x-1.0-beta5) and the PHPMailer (6.x-2.2) modules for messaging. I configured SMTP and PHP  messages, successfully sent and received test messages.
I am using the *Organic Groups* module and trying to utilize the messaging functions in it, for example receiving notifications for administrator users regarding membership approval.

Drupal isn't sending any mail. When I checked the recent log entries, it reports this error.

> Could not locate PHPMailer library

In /admin/messaging/settings I use HTML Mail (PHPMailer) as the default sending method.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The module relies on the PHPMailer class to send HTML mail.  So to send HTML e-mails using Messaging you first need to install PHPMailer.

Check the README.txt file at /messaging/messaging_phpmailer/ for PHPMailer installation instructions.